# Dictionaries entries with different structures

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, class

I have dictionaries in my Pokédex project that I fill with data imported from files, similar to APIs (or rather, I presume they actually are APIs? anyway, the files contain data with object structure).

What I always assumed, based on errors I got from VS, is that any element of the data must have the same structure. For example, the main dex list is structured like this for every pokémon:

```
{
    "name": "nameOfMon"
    "variants": {
        "standard": {data}
        "alt_1": {otherData}
    }
}
```

So every pokémon has the same type of properties in this structure, even though some are just empty (for example, not all have variants other than the standard one).

When using the data in the code, I cast a class on every pokémon, so when I will call its data will be like "`pokemon.name`".

While I understand that in the class constructor I need to define how the properties are defined (like for example name, being a set of `string, string`, what I actually wonder and would come in handy is: can I instead somehow structure the data of some pokémon omitting data that pokémon does not use?

Like for example, if a pokémon does not need the "variants" data, since it has just the standard one, is there a way to omit the "variants" data in the file and to make the dictionary just take the data from that pokémon skipping the data the pokémon does not contain? Like it's optional.

Comment: Make the optional property nullable?

Comment: You might want to read about [Polymorphic serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0). This lets you declare different classes for your different pokemons. That will make the serialization library only output the existing properties, as well as a `$type`-property so it knows what type to deserialize the object to.

Comment: I'll have to check this!

Comment: It seems this is kinda too advanced for me now, as I understand its consistence and kinda it's meaning, I'm not sure I'm able to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to do nothing:

```cs
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Name} {Age}";
}

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>("""{"Age": 42}""")); // --> 42
```

So, properties can be omitted in JSON. The absent fields will be initialized by default values of their types.

[In vice versa, you can mark properties to be required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties).

Comment: what I meant was more like the class has dictionary properties, like for example name being a dictionary<string, string>, so if i call pokemon.name or pokemon["name"] the value associated to "name" is obtained, but what if I want to have a pokemon who doesn't have a "name" property?

Comment: @grimoiredark If setting a name is optional then use a default value, eg. `class Pokemon { public string Name { get; set; } = "???"; /* ... */ }`

Comment: Does that work also with dictionaries? As i said, I'm not using straight variables but rather Dictionaries that I fill with data from files.

Comment: @grimoiredark No, but dictionaries filled with "data from files" are maybe also not the best fit for modeling everything - you probably want a combination of well-structured entity types and more flexible collection types like dictionaries, eg. `class Pokemon { string Name; Dictionary<string, VariantData> Variants; }`

Comment: well...basically it should work, at least in theory. i'll have to see if it's a suitable idea, i mean, there are 1000+ pokemon, i'd have to see if this solution is easy to handle for such a large collection of data! consider every pokemon has name, dict of dex nums, dict of egg groups, dict of variants which are each a dict of dicts which are dicts for the types, for the abilities, for the stats and for the locations in the games. so it would be a lot to rebuild. but thanks for now!